# Subspaces of matrices whose determinant is $0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Consider matrices of size $n\times n$ over finite field $\mathbb{F}_2$. It is linear space of dimension $n^2$.

\begin{bmatrix}
    x_{11}       & x_{12}  & \dots & x_{1n} \\
    x_{21}       & x_{22}  & \dots & x_{2n} \\
     \\
    x_{n1}       & x_{n2}  & \dots & x_{nn}
\end{bmatrix}

Now consider set of matrices for which some fixed rows are linearly dependent. For example: let $L$ is set of matrices for which first two rows are the same. It is clear that $L$ is a linear subspace of dimension $n^2-n$ and for all matrices of $L$ determinant is equal to $0$.

I am interested if the opposite is true. Let $L$ is subspace of dimension $n^2-n$ and determinant is $0$ for all matrices of $L$. Can we say that we can fix some set of rows which are linearly dependant for all matrices of $L$.

One can see that there are $2^n-1$ linear combination of rows. So the question is if there are any other subspaces of dimension $n^2-n$ whose determinant is $0$ or each of such subspaces is identified by some linear combination of rows.

Comment: If I understand this question correctly, the answer is no. Consider the collection of matrices which have $i$th row equal to $e_i$, and all other rows are $0$. Then if these matrixes are $M_i$, then $\det M_i = 0$ for all $i$, yet $\sum_{i=1}^n M_i = I$, which could have non-zero determinant, if $n$ is not divided by  $\operatorname{char} \mathbb{F}$.

Comment: @AlfredYerger The dimension of $\langle M_1,M_2,\ldots,M_n\rangle$ is $n$, not $n^2-n$.

Comment: I suppose there are also subspaces of that size involving two dependent columns.

Comment: You can also choose $n^2-n-1$ generators for which the first row equals the second row, and another generator with different raw dependencies...

Comment: Your $L$ is not a linear subspace. You want "sum to $0$", not "linearly dependent". Also, linear dependencies between **columns** rather than rows also lead to determinant-$0$ subspaces.

Comment: Note that the analogous question for matrices over a sufficiently large field (which $\mathbb{F}_2$, sadly, is not, but any infinite field is) has been answered by H. Flanders in [*On Spaces of Linear Transformations with Bounded Rank*](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1112/jlms/s1-37.1.10/pdf), Journal of the London Mathematical Society 37 (1962), 10--16. For a modern treatment, see Section 8.3 in [V. Prasolov, *Problems and theorems in linear algebra*](http://staff.math.su.se/mleites/books/prasolov-1994-problems.pdf).

Comment: When you say "finite field $F_2$ are you talking about the field of 2 elements?  You are of course assuming $n>1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An $n^2-n$ dimensional subspace of singular matrices in $M_n(\mathbb F)$ is either of the form $\{A\vert Ax=0\}$ for some column vector $x,$ or $\{A\vert \zeta A=0\}$ for some row vector $\zeta.$

Apparently, this was proved by Dieudonné, *Sur une généralisation du groupe orthogonal à quatre variables*. Arch. Math., 1 (1949). I haven't been able to access that article, but a more general result of Meshulam (with quite an easy to read proof) is available here: http://www2.math.technion.ac.il/~meshulam/eprints/maxrank.pdf - set $r=n-1$ in Theorem 3.

Comment: I will try to read Dieudonné's article. However, theorem 3 from Meshulam's article doesn't really solve the problem posted here, since it is written there that it was obtained assuming that $|F|\geqslant r+1$. And, in our case, $F=\mathbb{F}_2$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: Meshulam is just giving credit for the case $|F|\geq r+1.$ The point of his paper is to generalize to all $F.$

Comment: I missed that. I am sorry.