# Cosets of matrices whose determinant is $0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

[Subspaces of matrices whose determinant is $0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2498701/subspaces-of-matrices-whose-determinant-is-0)

In this question and in the linked answer is discussed following result.

Let $W$ be linear subspace in the space of matrices of size $n\times n$ over finite field $\mathbb F_q$. If $W$ has dimension that is $>n^2-n$ than it contains a matrix that is not singular.

Currently I am interested in the following problem. Lets take a coset, instead of a linear subspace. A coset is a subspace + one matrix. What is maximal dimension of coset that has only singular matrices.

I haven't found a coset of dimension $n^2-n$ (that is not a subspace) having that property. It is easy to find cosets of dimension $n^2-n -1$

One can see that following coset has only singular matrices and its dimension $5$.
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
    0       & \alpha_1   & \beta_1 \\
    0      & \alpha_2    & \beta_2 \\
    0       & 0          & \beta_3
\end{pmatrix}+
\begin{pmatrix}
    0       & 0   & 0 \\
    0      & 0    & 0 \\
    0       & 1          & 0
\end{pmatrix} 
\end{equation}